# How to send a SMS to many recipients?

Tags: android

How to send a SMS to many recipients in android? I want to send a SMS to many receivers in my application. I know this code:

```
Uri smsToUri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + 10086);
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, smsToUri);
                String message = "hello";
                // message = message.replace("%s", StoresMessage.m_storeName);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
                startActivity(intent);
```

This work for single recipient. But How to send the message to many recipients by using "ACTION_SENDTO" intent? That is too say, how to call the third-party application to send a SMS to many recipients in phone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

send sms to multiple numbers:

```
String strnum="10086;10086;10087;10089";
Uri smsToUri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + strnum);
```

or for Sending SMS to Multiple numbers using [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) see this post

[Unable to send sms using SmsManager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998655/unable-to-send-sms-using-smsmanager-in-android)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I test this method in Sumsung GAlaxy S2, the result is OK. But it can't work at HTC HD. If change the "," to ";", it also can work in HTC HD. Is there any common method which can run in any device? Or I need to detect the brand of the device to using the different separation?

Comment: 1)When I use ";", it's not working on Sumsung GAlaxy S2 but working on HTC HD. 2)When I use ",", it's working on Sumsung Galaxy S2 but not working on HTC HD.

Comment: which android version currently ruining on HTC HD?

Comment: The android version of HTC HD is 2.3.5. I get this information from "Setting" in HTC HD device. And the android version of Sumsung Galaxy S2 is 4.0.3

Comment: @Judy : but my answer is according to your question.if you have any device related problem then i think  first find Manufacture Name or Android Version before sending SMS.

Comment: @Judy This seems to be a known issue with Samsung devices. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9722290/1139908 for a snippet to detect Samsung phones.