# Implementation of sending SMS to group of contacts in android?

Tags: android, sms

In Android, I found that we use 
`android.telephony.SmsManager` to send SMS using the function void `sendTextmessage(..)`, with the field `destinationAddress = contact number`.

example:

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
String destinationAddress = "9508170711";
sm.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, null, "Test SMS Message", null, null);
```

What is the implementation/function to use if I have to send SMS to group of contacts retrieved from the phone book? If we use the same function `sendTextmessage(..)`.. what should the `destinationAddress` be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176270/how-to-send-a-sms-to-many-recipients

Comment: Is that the right way to do it? I mean looping around for each phone number & registering NEW BroadcastReceiver for each phone number & sending sms individually in the backend?

Comment: try this i hope work for u... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840057/sending-sms-to-multiple-contacts-stored-in-a-textview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840057/sending-sms-to-multiple-contacts-stored-in-a-textview